# How to install compiler and binutils on FreeNAS?

Tags: freebsd

I'd like to run a backup tool, [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), that apparently requires a `cc` compiler and `binutils`.  I'm able to locate and install the required BSD packages for python, gcc, and dependencies from [ftp2.freebsd.org](ftp://ftp2.freebsd.org/).  However, I can't find `binutils`.

How are `binutils` installed on a system like FreeNAS?  I'm working with FreeNAS 0.70 (based on FreeBSD 7.2).  I see several packages with `binutils` in the name, but it's not clear any of them are for my i386 platform.

e.g. I see `i386-rtems-binutils-2.19.1`, but I can't find any info that suggests this is correct for my platform.  Google results mention it's for realtime systems.

Comment: Have you already tried the solution offered to you on superuser.com?

Answer (score 3):

There is an extensive howto on how to get gcc and binutils running on a FreeBSD System at http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/custom-gcc/article.html As you say FreeNAS is based on FreeBSD, this probably applies here, too. But keep in mind, that compiling complex software on an embedded system isn't much fun. Probably you will have more success by setting up a cross-compiler on your main system and compile there the software for you FreeNAS system. See http://www.productionmonkeys.net/guides/freenas/building-freenas for a howto on this.

Comment: Is there any reason why you keep constantly editing old postings with changes of one or two characters? This is really annoying because they aren't really active. Sorry, I know no better place then to comment here...

Comment: Because I just realized there was a typo and so I fixed it because I care. What is wrong with it? Plus, I don't think I "keep constantly editing old postings". I don't think it have been more than 3 or 4 the last week. If there is more need to discuss this, let us move it over to a meta question.

Comment: The first link you give is dead. This is one of the reasons why we don't want links posted as answers. Could you include a summary of what it suggested in your answer?